# Knowing exactly which rows in data frame are causing runtime warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame to which I want to add a column `log_volume`:

```
df['log_volume'] = np.log(df.volume*df.close)
```

However, this gives me warning:

```
/home/rnj/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-Sn4ov4BM/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py:358: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
result = getattr(ufunc, method)(*inputs, **kwargs)
```

I wanted to know exactly which row of data frame is causing the warning. So, I tried something like this:

```
np.seterr(all='raise') #make it raise the warning so that it gets catched by except block

for index, row in df.head().iterrows():
    try:
        np.log(row.volume * row.close)
    except:
        errored_row = [row.date, row.tic, row.volume, row.close]
        print(str(errored_row))
```

However, this doesnt print anything. I debugged and realised that flow never goes inside `except` block.

When I reran first line (with `np.seterr(all='raise')` already executed):

```
df['log_volume'] = np.log(df.volume*df.close)
```

it appropriately gave me error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FloatingPointError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-a065385e90be> in <module>
----> 1 df['log_volume'] = np.log(df.volume*df.close)
      

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-Sn4ov4BM/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
   1934         self, ufunc: Callable, method: str, *inputs: Any, **kwargs: Any
   1935     ):
-> 1936         return arraylike.array_ufunc(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
   1937 
   1938     # ideally we would define this to avoid the getattr checks, but

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-Sn4ov4BM/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py in array_ufunc(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
    356         # ufunc(series, ...)
    357         inputs = tuple(extract_array(x, extract_numpy=True) for x in inputs)
--> 358         result = getattr(ufunc, method)(*inputs, **kwargs)
    359     else:
    360         # ufunc(dataframe)

FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in log
```

So, what I am missing here?

Comment: `(df.volume * df.close) == 0`?

Comment: Ended up doing  `df['log_volume'] = np.where((df.volume*df.close) != 0, np.log(df.volume*df.close), 0)`